# Burning Ubuntu ISO image into Hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, iso

i'd like to boot my Linux kernel from my hard disk with a GUI. How may I burn an Ubuntu ISO image to my hard disk, which will be connected to an embedded board, so that when I boot my embedded device, there's already a Ubuntu OS with GUI for my development?

thanks!

Comment: I doubt your embedded board will be able to run Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: Why not just install to the hard disk?

Comment: Woeitg, it's more for learning purposes. i'm not familiar building a Linux kernel image at this juncture and would need to quickly get a development environment up. Melebius, meaning, connect the hard disk to my host PC and then install from there, before connecting back to my embedded device? grooveplex, my embedded board is a SoC, running ARM cortex A17, would it be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

I kind of agree with Woeitg's comment, but if you really need to do this then it *should* work if you "dd" the iso to a blank hard drive.
The command would be something like this:

```
root@localhost$ dd if=/home/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=2M
```

Be careful! If you get the target wrong you could wipe your hard drive.
To check which drive is which try:

```
root@localhost$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
```

That will show the brand/make of your hard drive and which sdX udev has assigned it.

Comment: i see. my current setup is that, my hard disk is connected to my embedded target board; and target board is connected to my host Ubuntu PC via NFS. So how do I access the HDD and flash in Ubuntu with GUI through my host Ubuntu PC?

Comment: Do I need to reconfigure my bootloader to boot from HDD? My current bootloader only has usbboot option.